# Converting Lower Case Characters in a Text File to Upper Case Letters and Vice Versa

Tags: c, file, io

I have a text file that contains the following text, without a new line character...

```
Hello World
```

I would like to convert the lower case characters to upper case, and vice versa, so that the same text file would end up with the following text...

```
hELLOW wORLD
```

Unfortuntately, when I run my code, it goes into an endless loop.  When I step through the code, I see that fseek() goes back one byte for the first loop, as expected, but it goes back two bytes for the second and subsequent loops.  I don't understand why it goes back two bytes instead of one.  Why is this the case?  Can someone please help?

Here's my code...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    int ch;
    long offset;

    fp = fopen("c:\\users\\domenic\\desktop\\test.txt", "r+");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("error:  unable to open file\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    offset = ftell(fp);
    while (1)
    {
        ch = fgetc(fp);
        if (ch == EOF)
            break;
        if (isupper(ch))
        {
            fseek(fp, offset, SEEK_SET);
            fputc(tolower(ch), fp);
        }
        else if (islower(ch))
        {
            fseek(fp, offset, SEEK_SET);
            fputc(toupper(ch), fp);
        }
        offset = ftell(fp);
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint. You are just toggling the 6th-bit in each `a-z` and `A-Z` character.

Comment: `fgetc` returns an **`int`**, therefore declare `int ch`. I think reading after writing still requires that you *flush* first.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, that can be true as long as we're with Latin alphabet. Any locale-specific char would blow that logic.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin To toggle case with `A-Z` and `a-z`: `fputc(ch ^ ('A' ^ 'a'), fp);` - at least it works for ASCII _and_ [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC).

Comment: `:)` now we have hit the weeds... *"EBCDIC descended from the code used with punched cards and the corresponding six bit binary-coded decimal code used with most of IBM's computer peripherals of the late 1950s and early 1960s"*

Comment: @chux I don't have an EBCDIC computer but `'A' ^ 'a'` is just `(1 << 5)` or `32` for ASCII, where it would be `(1 << 6)` or `64` for EBCDIC. Nice trick.

Comment: @Antti Haapala Flushing the output stream before reading the next character worked.  Thank you very much for your help!  I really appreciate it!

Comment: Thank you everyone else for your help as well.  Much appreciated it!

Comment: @YurySchkatula Not true for "ÿ" either. I think we're agreeing that tolower and toupper are preferred over bit toggling. They respect the configured character set and locale.

Comment: @Antti Haapala I've edited my post to declare `ch` as an `int`, as per your suggestion.  Actually, I initially had it declared as such, but changed it to see whether it was the cause of the behaviour.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you just want to change *upper* to *lower* and *lower* to *upper* throughout a file, you may be making it a bit harder on yourself than it need be.

Before we look at an approach to make things a bit easier, let's talk about avoiding *magic numbers* and *hardcoded paths* within your code. C provides a definition for `main` that allows you to provide arguments to your code to avoid hardcoding values (such as file/path names) -- use them. The proper invocation of `main` with arguments is:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
```

(or you will see the equivalent `int main (int argc, char **argv)`)

The invocation without arguments is `int main (void)`.

Now on to the question at hand. As mentioned in my comment, when dealing with ASCII, the *bit* that controls the case is the 6th-bit -- and from the discussion, if you are dealing with EBCDIC, the *case-bit`is the 7th-bit. As @chux pointed out both can be handled seamlessly by determining the appropriate bit`A ^ a`for both (the result is`32`, e.g.`(1 << 5)`for ASCII, and`64`or`(1 << 6)`for EBCDIC. To toggle any bit on/off you simply XOR the *case-bit* with the current character`(A-Za-z)`. So far any character`'c'`, you wish to toggle the case of, you simply XOR it with`A ^ a`, e.g.

```
if (('A' <= c && c <= 'Z') || ('a' <= c && c <= 'z'))
    c ^= A ^ a;
```

If `c` was uppercase, it's now lowercase, and vice-versa.

To do that for an entire file, taking the filename to convert as the first argument to the program (or reading from `stdin` by default if no argument is given) and outputting the resulting case-converted to `stdout`, you could do something as simple as the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int c;
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)          /* read each char */
        /* is it a letter ? */
        if (('A' <= c && c <= 'Z') || ('a' <= c && c <= 'z'))
            putchar (c ^ ('A' ^ 'a'));      /* toggle case */
        else
            putchar (c);                    /* just output */

    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);    /* close file if not stdin */

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Input**

```
$ cat dat/captnjack.txt
This is a tale
Of Captain Jack Sparrow
A Pirate So Brave
On the Seven Seas.
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/case_toggle < dat/captnjack.txt
tHIS IS A TALE
oF cAPTAIN jACK sPARROW
a pIRATE sO bRAVE
oN THE sEVEN sEAS.
```

If you want to write the output to a new file, simply redirect the output, e.g.

```
$ ./bin/case_toggle < dat/captnjack.txt > dat/captnjack_toggled.txt
```

Which would write the case-toggled output to `dat/captnjack_toggled.txt`.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: It's an interesting way to toggle the case.  And it's also interesting how `stdin` is used to make the command line argument optional.  That's great.  David, thank you very much for the information.  I really appreciated it!

Answer (score 0):

To start off, fputc does not delete or rather act like an "insert" after you use fseek to go back 1 character.

In this case you are:

1. getting a char
2. fseek to before the char
3. placing a upper/lowercase char before the char found in step 2
4. setting new offset to right after your new character.

You probably get alot of hEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE in your text file after exiting your endless loop?

To fix this I would create a temporary new file.. something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp, *new_f;
    int ch;
    long offset;

    fp = fopen("test.txt", "r+");
    new_f = fopen("test2.txt", "w" );

    if ( fp == NULL || new_f == NULL )
    {
        printf("error:  unable to open file\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    offset = ftell(fp);
    while (1)
    {
        ch = fgetc(fp);

        if (ch == EOF)
            break;

        if( !isalpha( ch ) )
        {
            fputc( ch, new_f );
        }
        else if (isupper(ch))
        {
            fputc(tolower(ch), new_f );
        }
        else if (islower(ch))
        {
            fputc(toupper(ch), new_f);
        }
    }

    fclose( fp );
    fclose( new_f );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is not the result then `"hELLOWwORLD"` and not `"hELLOW wORLD"`?

Comment: You're right. 

In that case, a check needs to be in place for non characters.

Something such as:

    if( !isalpha( ch ) )
    { 
        fputc( ch, new_f );
    }
I will edit my post to fix that, thank you.

Comment: ... or simply `if (isupper(ch)) 
            fputc(tolower(ch), new_f ); else fputc(toupper(ch), new_f);`

Comment: Ahh I didn't realize isupper checked if it is alphabetic too :) Thanks AGAIN

Comment: @Corey Your method of using a separate file is definitely the more practical one.  But I wanted to understand why my code was behaving the way it was.  It looks like I simply needed to flush the output stream before reading the next character.  Thanks for your help, though, I really appreciate it!